# Cargar fichero de texto a mysql, usando script sql

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando cargar un archivo de texto con el siguiente formato, a mysql:

```
Clave Area¶Area de Venta¶F. Contable¶Sesión¶Fecha de Apertura¶Hora de Apertura¶AV/P¶Transacción¶Operación¶ID DE VTA¶Tipo¶Origen¶Destino¶Fecha Salida¶Hora Salida¶Folio Boleto¶Asiento¶Nombre Pasajero¶Tipo¶Formas de Pago¶EF¶TB¶PU¶TR¶DO¶GP¶CV¶Importe¶Formato/Salto¶Fecha Venta¶Hora Venta¶Corrida¶Empresa Corrida¶Tipo de Boleto¶Numero de Referencia¶Clave de Autorizacion¶Voucher¶Tipo de Servicio¶F. Cierre¶Razon Social¶R.F.C.¶DOCUMENTO ¶ EMPRESA¶

006¶ACAPULCO CENTRO¶01/01/2016¶231658¶01/01/2016¶06:44:22¶ACAEE67892¶5155690¶7978798¶¶CS¶ACAC¶OMET¶01/01/2016¶12:15¶T-A-04131772¶13¶GRISELDA BARAJAS GUERRERO¶¶EF¶146.00¶0.00¶0.00¶0.00¶0.00¶0.00¶0.00¶146.00¶¶01/01/2016¶07:49:40¶028376¶AUTOTRANSPORTES COSTEñOS¶ADULTO¶00000000000000000000¶¶0¶ECONOMICO¶01/01/2016¶¶¶0¶¶Þ
006¶ACAPULCO CENTRO¶01/01/2016¶231658¶01/01/2016¶06:44:22¶ACAEE67892¶5155690¶7978799¶¶CS¶ACAC¶OMET¶01/01/2016¶12:15¶T-A-04131773¶14¶MARGARITA CARVAJAL NAVA¶¶EF¶146.00¶0.00¶0.00¶0.00¶0.00¶0.00¶0.00¶146.00¶¶01/01/2016¶07:49:40¶028376¶AUTOTRANSPORTES COSTEñOS¶ADULTO¶00000000000000000000¶¶0¶ECONOMICO¶01/01/2016¶¶¶0¶¶Þ
006¶ACAPULCO CENTRO¶01/01/2016¶231658¶01/01/2016¶06:44:22¶ACAEE67892¶5155690¶7978800¶¶CS¶ACAC¶OMET¶01/01/2016¶12:15¶T-A-04131774¶17¶JULIA YARIN CASTILLO BARAJAS¶¶EF¶146.00¶0.00¶0.00¶0.00¶0.00¶0.00¶0.00¶146.00¶¶01/01/2016¶07:49:40¶028376¶AUTOTRANSPORTES COSTEñOS¶ADULTO¶00000000000000000000¶¶0¶ECONOMICO¶01/01/2016¶¶¶0¶¶Þ
```

La estructura de la tabla tiene 45 campos, en el archivo campos = 44 la tabla tiene un campo adicional, que es un id autoincremental, el cuál no viene como columna en el fichero.
Entonces intento insertar los 44 campos del fichero de texto y que el id vaya incrementando. Como normalmente pasa al ingresar registros.

Pero no se pueden insertar las filas, pienso que por que me falta indicarle la forma de inserción y/o de exepción o salto de ese campo id auto-incremental.

¿Cuál debe ser la forma correcta de sintaxis en el script, si necesito darle formato: YY/MONTH/DAY al campo fecha, y escribir las filas en la tabla?

Script SQL

```
load data local infile 'c:\\ventas\\ventas.txt' into table ventas306

        fields terminated by '¶' lines terminated by 'Þ' IGNORE 1 LINES 


        (@fecha_contable, @fecha_apertura, @fecha_salida, @fecha_venta, @fecha_cierre)
        SET fecha_contable = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_contable, "%Y %M %d"),
        SET fecha_apertura = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_apertura, "%Y %M %d"),
        SET fecha_salida = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_salida, "%Y %M %d"),
        SET fecha_venta = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_venta, "%Y %M %d"),
        SET fecha_cierre = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_cierre, "%Y %M %d")

        (clave_area,area_vta,fecha_contable,sesion,fecha_apertura,hora_apertura,av_p,transaccion,operacion,
        id_vta,tipo,origen,destino,fecha_salida,hra_salida,f_boleto,asiento,pasajero,campo19,f_pago,ef,
        tb,pu,tr,doo,gp,cv,importe,formato_salto,fecha_venta,hra_venta,corrida,empresa_corrida,t_boleto,
        referencia,autorizacion,voucher,t_servicio,fecha_cierre,razon_social,rfc,documento,empresa,fin)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intente lo siguiente (no todas la columnas son incluidas en el ejemplo):

MySQL:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ventas306`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ventas306` (
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `clave_area` CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  `area_vta` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_contable` DATE NOT NULL
);
```

File: `/path/to/file/ventas.txt`

```txt
Clave Area¶Area de Venta¶F. ContableÞ
006¶ACAPULCO CENTRO¶01/01/2016Þ
006¶ACAPULCO CENTRO¶02/01/2016Þ
006¶ACAPULCO CENTRO¶03/01/2016Þ
```

MySQL:

```sql
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file/ventas.txt'
    ->   INTO TABLE `ventas306`
    ->   FIELDS TERMINATED BY '¶'
    ->   OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    ->   LINES TERMINATED BY 'Þ'
    ->   IGNORE 1 LINES
    ->   (`clave_area`, `area_vta`, @`fecha_contable`)
    ->   SET `fecha_contable` = STR_TO_DATE(@`fecha_contable`, '%d/%m/%Y');
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                               |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1638 | Non-ASCII separator arguments are not fully supported |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `id`,
    ->   `clave_area`,
    ->   `area_vta`,
    ->   `fecha_contable`
    -> FROM
    ->   `ventas306`;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

La recomendación sería cambiar el carácter de terminación de líneas (`LINES TERMINATED BY`) en el fichero `ventas.txt` y en el `LOAD DATA`.

File: `/path/to/file/ventas.txt`

```txt
Clave Area¶Area de Venta¶F. Contable
006¶ACAPULCO CENTRO¶01/01/2016
006¶ACAPULCO CENTRO¶02/01/2016
006¶ACAPULCO CENTRO¶03/01/2016
```

MySQL:

```sql
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file/ventas.txt'
    ->   INTO TABLE `ventas306`
    ->   FIELDS TERMINATED BY '¶'
    ->   OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    ->   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    ->   IGNORE 1 LINES
    ->   (`clave_area`, `area_vta`, @`fecha_contable`)
    ->   SET `fecha_contable` = STR_TO_DATE(@`fecha_contable`, '%d/%m/%Y');
Query OK, 3 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                               |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1638 | Non-ASCII separator arguments are not fully supported |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `id`,
    ->   `clave_area`,
    ->   `area_vta`,
    ->   `fecha_contable`
    -> FROM
    ->   `ventas306`;
+----+------------+------ ----------+-----------------+
| id | clave_area | area_vta        | fecha_contable  |
+----+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  1 | 006        | ACAPULCO CENTRO | 2016-01-01      |
|  2 | 006        | ACAPULCO CENTRO | 2016-01-02      |
|  3 | 006        | ACAPULCO CENTRO | 2016-01-03      |
+----+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```